# Site will not load. Why is ":4001" showing up in my browser's address bar when this happens?

Tags: wordpress, migration, request

I've migrated a local install of Wordpress to my host.

Now, when I attempt to load the site (ex. "www.mynewsite.com") the browser will churn for a while, then report that my site couldn't be loaded because it's taking too long to respond.

I notice that the address bar of my browser now reads: www.mynewsite.com:4001

What does it mean when ":4001" becomes tagged on at the end of your url?

Answer (score 1):

What was your basic wordpress configuration? You need to set the website address in the wp-config.php while moving your wordpress website to a new host. This is just because when you install wordpress on localhost it takes the 127.0.0.1 as native path, what you need is to reconfigure the configuration file, it looks like your local setup ran on 4001 port!

Comment: I was running Wordpress locally using a program called Instant Wordpress, not the usual method of WAMP/LAMP/XAMP. 

From the program's documentation, it seems that it was supposed to run on the 4001 port.
As per your instructions, is this the line I should be editing in the config file:

`code` define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); `code`

Comment: No , not this line , you should add this to your wp-config.php file :
`code`
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.your-website-name.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.your-website-name.com');
`code`

Replace `code`http://www.your-website-name.com`code` with the name of your website.

Comment: Say thanks by marking this as the answer to your question! 

Best!

Answer (score 1):

:4001 is your port number, it looks like your site was developed on that port, connect to your website's database and edit your WP installation's options table (default wp_options) update entries `siteurl` and `home` (usually entries 1 and 37 respectively) to your new url.

if you were developing locally using a host name identical to your live site you will need to disable the host name so you can view the live site.